# Does any browser have a standard for reporting ignored input errors?

Tags: accessibility

Do any browser standards support a method for reporting that the user has entered an invalid, ignored keystroke into an input?

Say you implement an HTML input behavior that ignores characters that do not conform to a format. AngularUI Mask does this. Here's a demo: http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask/master/demo/index.html. Try this:

- Set the "Predefined masks" to one of the phone number formats, e.g. (999) 999-9999.
- Use the ChromeVox screen reader to interact with the input.
- Enter invalid characters, like the letter `t`.

The reader will say the letter `t`, but the masked input ignores the invalid character.

This presents an accessibility problem. Is there a way to signal a global object like `window` that an error occurred, or is does any library provide a way to provide an audible response when the users provide errant and ignored input?

Comment: The closest published proposal I found is `window.getAttention()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getAttention). It's not a solution, though. It is narrowly supported, and I would guess that it was not intended for the use I seek.

[1]:

Answer (score 0):

The example doesn't work well with JAWS or VoiceOver so there are more issues than just the masked characters

With VO, in the first two parts of the phone number, VO echoes the first two numbers I type but doesn't say the third number, probably because it's moving the cursor.

For example, (123) 456-7890.  When I type '1', I hear '1'.  When I type '2', I hear '2'.  When I type '3', I hear *nothing*.  Same with 4, 5, 6.  The 4 and 5 are echoed but 6 is not.  The last 4 digits are announced as I type them.

With JAWS, the '1' is echoed but the remaining digits are not announced as I type them until I get to the end of the number, then it says '2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0'.

If all those issues were fixed, then I would handle the masked characters by using a (visually) hidden `<span aria-live='assertive'>` and would update the contents of the span with something like "letter T ignored".  That way the screen reader would tell you the letter was ignored.